# Java JFrame horizontal resize of JTextField, JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, layout-manager

When I resize a window, the buttons stay the same size. How can I do a horizontal resizing when I change the JFrame window size?

I want the horizontal size of userTextArea and typeList to expand and contract depending o if the user increases or decreases the window area.

```
public ClearQuestWindow(String title){


protected JTextField userTextArea;

protected JLabel userLabel;
protected JLabel typeLabel;

protected JComboBox typeList;

    super(title);
    setLayout(null);
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(790, 625));

    // Set to system look and feel
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error setting native LAF: " + e);
    }

    //Text field instantiation
    userTextArea = new JTextField();

   //Labels instantiation
    userLabel = new JLabel("User Name:");
    typeLabel = new JLabel("Type:");


    //ComboBox instantiation
    typeList = new JComboBox(typeString);



    userLabel.setSize(100, 30);
    userLabel.setLocation(10, 80 );
    userLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    userTextArea.setLocation(100, 85);
    userTextArea.setSize(150, 23);

    typeLabel.setSize(100, 30);
    typeLabel.setLocation(10, 110 );
    typeLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
    typeLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    typeList.setLocation(100, 115);
    typeList.setSize(150, 23);
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first step in solving this problem is to get rid of nonsense like `setLayout(null);`.   ***Use layouts!***  There are layouts that respect the preferred size of components, while others will stretch them to available space.

Comment: Have a look at the [Layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: If you only want the second compnent on each line to expand then you should be able to use either the SpringLayout or the GridBagLayout. See the example from the link above.

Answer (score 0):

`GridBagLayout` is a flexible Layout Manager and should suit your purpose:

```
mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
mainFrame.add(label, c);
```

Use `Fill` when the component's display area is larger than the component's requested size to determine whether and how to resize the component. Valid values (defined as `GridBagConstraints` constants) include `NONE` (the default), `HORIZONTAL` (make the component wide enough to fill its display area horizontally, but do not change its height), `VERTICAL` (make the component tall enough to fill its display area vertically, but do not change its width), and `BOTH` (make the component fill its display area entirely).

[For more information on the GridBagLayout click this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)